# Avoid Conflict between the events in google calendar android

Tags: android, google-calendar-api

I'm creating an android app that creates an event in google calendar using app.

Now it is creating an event properly, but there is a problem. If I schedule the first event from 1pm to 3pm, it should not create a second event if it is on 1.30pm to 2pm on the same day.

So what I'm saying is I want to avoid time conflict (double booking) between the time in same date.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you resolved this?

Answer (score 0):

Try not to create an event directly to the calendar. Instead, use invitations. If you read through [this blog](https://robinpowered.com/blog/how-to-prevent-double-booking-events-in-google-calendar/), you'll know that Google Calendars are set to 'Automatically add all invitations to this calendar', which can cause double booking.
Use events.insert().
More on that in [Calendar API docs](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/create-events).
You can also play and test this using [Calendar try-it](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/create-events#try_it).